# User Created Open Graph Objects in Facebook App

Tags: facebook, object, facebook-opengraph, creation

I'm trying to build a Facebook App that will run in the Canvas on Facebook. I want to give users the ability to create custom open graph objects. For example I want users to be able to make a donation bucket. Title, Description, amount needed, time left, goal. I want the user to make these and then when someone contributes it will post saying "USER_NAME added to the donation TITLE"

Is it possible for users to create objects in this way? Most of what I've seen is about the developer making objects and users acting on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Open Graph object is basically just an URL, that provides the relevant info via appropriate meta elements.

So where’s the problem? You just provide an URL that provides the data your user entered – this could f.e. just contain an id as GET parameter, which let’s your script read the relevant data out of your database and fill the meta elements with it.